# Checking header files who are not used in main()

Tags: c++, header, include, intellisense

My question is if the compiler/intellisense is going through header/cpp files who are not used in main(). Or do I have to put every function from a class inside the main() to check if its correct (the classes are in the same directory of course) ? Because lately I can write completely wrong code.
For example

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h" // some class 
bool foo::bar()
{
 return "a";
}
```

But if I dont put it in my main() it will compile (if the code inside main is correct of course). I tried to build, clean, rebuild, restart, reinstall and so on. Still I get no errors. Even if I include it in my main.cpp, it still will build and compile.

I use Visual Studio 2013 Professional x86 version. As OS Windows 7 x64

**EDIT:**

Hmmm still not running like it should. Visual Studio doesnt recognize the .cpp file I guess. I get no errors or warnings. Also it seems that Visual Assists does not move my methods after I press "create method implementation" to my .cpp file. I tried to reinstall Visual Studio 2013, updated it to and also reinstalled Visual Assist. I don't really get it. Does this happend to anybody before ?

Answer (score 2):

Your function `foo::bar()` is actually valid C++:  `"a"` is a string literal, which is an array of characters.  Like all arrays, it is implicitly convertible to a pointer to its initial element, and like all pointers, that pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool` (with `nullptr` becoming `false` and all other pointers becoming `true`).

The compiler will compile all of the source files in your project.  Only if it can determine that a source file *and* all of the headers included by that source file is unchanged, will it skip recompilation of that source file.  If you don't include a header in any source file, that header will never be compiled.  Whether code is or is not used from `main()` is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry that was a bad example. I actually can write anything and it will be accepted.

I think that would be more correct.
bool foo::bar()
  {
}

It seems that VS doesnt care what I write. Because I can just smash my head against the keyboard and still get no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Compiler compiles all the header files which are included in the folder. If header file is having any error, you will be informed for that and compile error would occur.

Comment: I see. I guess it is Visual Studio 2013/IntelliSense then. Which is weird because it used to work just fine and I surley didn't change any settings.